# Setting Data Source in code behind for inline xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

Please take a look at following code. I am trying to dynamically add a data column with Checkbox template. As you can see i am also using a Data Context proxy for binding IsChecked value of the check box. However I cannot figure out how to set the Binding source in this case.

```
GridViewDataColumn dataColumn = new GridViewDataColumn(); 
                // setup the header
                dataColumn.Header = "sample"; 
                dataColumn.HeaderTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                dataColumn.IsGroupable = false;
                dataColumn.IsFilterable = true;
                dataColumn.IsSortable = false;
                //// set the width

                dataColumn.MinWidth = 100;
                // setup the binding


                DataContextProxy dcProxy = new DataContextProxy();
                dcProxy.Name = "proxy";
                dcProxy.DataContext = this.DataContext;

            string checkBoxTemplate = string.Format(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" 
                                                        xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
                                                        <CheckBox  IsChecked=""{{Binding Path=DataSource.IsVersionIncluded,Mode=TwoWay}}"" IsThreeState=""False""/>
                                                        </DataTemplate>", dcProxy.DataSource);
            dataColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(checkBoxTemplate);

            Binding binding = new Binding();


            binding.Source = dcProxy;

            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataSource.IsVersionIncluded");
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            dataColumn.DataMemberBinding = binding;

            //add column to TreeListView
            radTreeListView.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
```

Here is the boolean property in ViewModel which i intend to hit once user checks/unchecks the checkbox in grid cell which is currently not happening.

```
private bool _isVersionIncluded = false;
    public bool IsVersionIncluded
    {
        get { return _isVersionIncluded; }
        set
        {
            _isVersionIncluded = value;

        }
    }
```

Please could anybody tell what am I missing here? Many Thanks.

Omer Javed

Answer (score 0):

you are not using  [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  in your property

```
private bool _isVersionIncluded = false;
public bool IsVersionIncluded
{
    get { return _isVersionIncluded; }
    set
    {
        _isVersionIncluded = value;

    }
}
```